# Heroku Migrate not Applying Migrations(Django)

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration, migrate

[image: heroku run python manage.py migrate]
From the first image heroku run python/python3 manage.py migrate is running successfully and applying the migrations.

[image: heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser]
From the second image while trying to create a superuser, I get the error 'unapplied migrations'

I have been debugging for almost an hour and it's getting into my nerves. A solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "You have 40 unapplied migrations" is not an error it's warning.
you can still go ahead and create the superuser.

And the following warning you shared above could be due database configuration.
Confirm whether the Database URL in the settings.py

If issue still persists, you can try recreating the database on Heroku and then apply migrations:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm app-name
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I found the issue. I was using a different environment variable in my .env